# Very Quick Custom Pluggable Function Question

Tags: plugin-development

Lets say I have a function set up like such:

```
add_action( 'init', 'jigoshop_add_to_cart_action' );

function jigoshop_add_to_cart_action($url = false){
//code
}
```

To make it pluggable by others plugins, I just need to change this to

```
add_action( 'init', 'jigoshop_add_to_cart_action' );
if (!function_exists('jigoshop_add_to_cart_action')) { //ADD THIS
function jigoshop_add_to_cart_action($url = false){
//code
}
} //AND THIS
```

right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because you're hooking it to an init action, then somebody can replace the function simply by unhooking it themselves. You don't really need to wrap it or make it pluggable.

Comment: otto, i don't follow why this isn't considered pluggable?  is it considered pluggable only if it cannot be unhooked?

Comment: It is pluggable, but it's unnecessarily so. In other words, there's no need to have this extra code at all, because if somebody wants to replace it, then all they really have to do is to unhook it and hook in their own function. Simpler, easier to manage. Pluggable functions are pretty bad mojo and should generally be avoided.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I agree mostly, but I think they're a nice feature for people who don't understand hooks and filters... excerpt they probably train people to think you can override ANY function, when you can't. queue WSOD.

Comment: Actions and filters are easy to learn and better to use. I'd stick to them, and help improve the general programming skill level. :)